# Install RAID driver on HP DL380 G9

Tags: redhat, hp, hp-proliant, drivers, hp-smart-array

I'm trying to install RHEL 6.2 on HP DL380 G9, but the I cannot find the storage during the installation. I thought maybe RHEL 6.2 does not support HP P440AR contoller by default, then I go to HP support site to download the driver of P440ar for RHEL 6u2 (hpsa-3.4.6-171.rhel6u2.x86_64.dd.gz ). I have unziped this file and dd to my USB stick then I found it's contain a RPM file, I have no idea about how to install a RPM package at the begining of the RHEL 6.2 installation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**As a lesson to people who try to install old versions of Linux on new hardware, this won't work...**

- [RHEL 6.2 was released in December 2011](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux#RHEL_6)
- The [HP ProLiant DL380 Gen9 server](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/proliant-servers/product-detail.html?oid=7271241) was released a few weeks ago in late 2014...

HP's [compatibility matrix](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/supportmatrix/exceptions/rhel_exceptions.aspx#.VI26k8bDvSw) states the certified operating systems and *minimum* versions needed to operate on a given hardware platform.

[image]

For the server you have, RHEL 6.5 will work *if* you add the driver disk available from [Red Hat here](https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/69/ver=/rhel---6/6.5/x86_64/product-downloads). Or really, **just install RHEL 6.6**, as it contains everything you need to run on this hardware.

If there's some unfortunate reason you ***need*** to use RHEL 6.2 (*policy, certification, bad boss*), **virtualize it** or use period-correct hardware (DL380p Gen8 or DL380 G7).

Comment: This does NOT work in CentOS 6.6. I have a Proliant DL380 Gen9 with the HP Smart Array P440ar controller as well, and my default 6.6 image doesn't know how to use this controller either.

Comment: I just installed this combination 30 minutes ago on a Gen9 DL380. It works fine. You may be running into another issue. Are you using a kickstart or customized deployment solution? Is the server running in UEFI mode?

Answer (score 1):

We encountered the same issue and testing using a CentOS 6.6 image seemed to work fine. We also had to disable to UEFI option and enable Legacy BIOS MODE in order to PXE boot.

Cheers